# Vba: KeyDown events stops working after clicking a button

Tags: vba, click, keydown

Excuse me for asking. I've been reading for 3 hours and I couldn't solve this yet. How can I make a form to respond to KeyDown events again after mouse clicking a button . At first it responds to letter "n" on the keyboard ,for example. But if the user chooses to click on a button Keydown events won't fire anymore.
I tried calling the code which sets my form to wait for keydown events but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Btn_NextStudent_Click()
    MsgBox "You clicked the button" 
    'GETS READY FOR KEYDOWN EVENTS AGAIN (*****THIS DOESN'T WORK*****)
    TabstopFocusOnClick      
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()   
    'PREPARAR CONTROLES PARA LOS EVENTOS KEYDOWN
    TabstopFocusOnClick         
End Sub

Sub TabstopFocusOnClick()
    Dim I As Integer

    '''PARA USAR EVENTOS DE TECLAS PRESIONADAS EN EL TECLADO
    On Error Resume Next
    For I = 0 To Controls.Count - 1   ' Use the Controls collection
        Controls(I).TabStop = False
        Controls(I).TakeFocusOnClick = False
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    'AL PRESIONAR "N" 
    If KeyCode = 78 Then
        Btn_NextStudent_Click
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be simpler to implement a Key Logger.

Comment: What is the active/selected control when it doesnot work anymore? Don't use a message box and don't call event-handlers

Comment: EvR, so sorry for my delayed reply.  I just used a Msgbox to simplify code reading on this site, just as an example. You mean I shouldn't use this?:
 Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
TinMan, I will read about Key Logger. I think I haven't tried it, yet.